# projecting an array of strings with mongoose aggregate

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

My User DB -

[image]

Want to get the `inBagProducts`.

What I've tried -

```
type product = Pick<IUser, 'id' | 'inBagProducts'>;

const products: ReadonlyArray<product> = await UserDB.aggregate<product>(
  [
    {
      $match: { owner: req.userId! },
    },
    {
      $sort: { createdAt: -1 },
    },
    {
      $project: { inBagProducts: 1 },
    },
  ]
);

console.log(products.map((product) => product.inBagProducts));
```

Didn't work.
I know the `userId` I'm getting is correct.

The upper mention `IUser` interface -

```
interface IUser extends IDBCollection {
    readonly fullname: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
    inBagProducts: string[];
    tokens: Readonly<{ _id?: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, token: string }>[];
}
```

User schema -

```
const userSchema: mongoose.Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fullname: {
        type: String,
        minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 26,
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true,
        maxlength: 320,
        required: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    inBagProducts: {
        type: [mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId],
    },
    tokens: {
        type: [{
            token: { type: String },
        }],
        default: [],
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});
```

I want to get the inBagProducts Array from DB.

Comment: Please mention both user and related schema you want to get data from.
Also describe what exactly you need to get from this 2 schema ?

Comment: @Dipten same schemas

Comment: @Dipten added the schema

Comment: `$match: { owner: req.userId! }` - I don't see an 'owner' field in the schema?

Comment: @Brgbegnefneg Please mention product schema. and describe 'owner' field use in any of the schema.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68854822/taking-an-array-of-ids-in-db-lookup-to-another-collection-with-the-same-id-a=

@Dipten