# Taking an array of id's in DB, $lookup to another collection with the same id, and project the data by the id - mongoose with TS

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

Here is what I've tried -

```
const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
    type product = Pick<IUser, 'id' | 'inBagProducts'>;

    const products: ReadonlyArray<product> = await UserDB.aggregate<product>([
      {
        $match: { _id: ObjectId(req.userId) },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'products',
          foreignField: '_id',
          localField: '_id',
          as: 'products',
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'products',
          foreignField: 'products._id',
          localField: '_id',
          as: 'products',
        },
      },
      { 
        $project: {
          inBagProducts: 1,
          productsCounter: { $size: '$products' },
          'products._id': 1,
          'products.category': 1,
          'products.gender': 1,
          'products.title': 1,
          'products.description': 1,
          'products.price': 1,
          'products.imageFileName': 1,
          'products.createdAt': 1,
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: '$products',
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
        },
      },
      {
        $sort: { 'products.createdAt': -1 },
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: '$_id',
          category: { $first: '$category' },
          gender: { $first: '$gender' },
          title: { $first: '$title' },
          description: { $first: '$description' },
          price: { $first: '$price' },
          imageFileName: { $first: '$imageFileName' },
          products: { $push: '$products' },
        },
      },
      {
        $unset: ['_id', 'products.createdAt'],
      },
    ]);
```

Didn't work.

The User DB with the id's of products -

[image]

Product object in DB -

[image]

Data sample -

product -

```
{
"category": 5,
"gender": 2,
"title": "my sneakers",
"description": "res sniks",
"price": 3222,
"imageFileName": "http://localhost:3000../../images1628875160365-2008.png",
"createdAt": {
    "$date": "2021-08-13T17:19:20.399Z"
},
"updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2021-08-13T17:19:20.399Z"
},
"__v": 0
```

}

user -

```
{
    "inBagProducts": [{
        "$oid": "6115a5a5ff5cdc56e8b00bbe"
    }, {
        "$oid": "610c8269da39093228dbe285"
    }, {
        "$oid": "6114fc131a509c32808a9baa"
    }, {
        "$oid": "6115a592ff5cdc56e8b00bbd"
    }, {
        "$oid": "610c8269da39093228dbe285"
    }],
    "fullname": "rrrrrrrrrrrrrrr",
    "email": "3@1223.com",
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2021-08-19T10:18:19.427Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2021-08-19T10:48:32.022Z"
    },
    "__v": 10
}
```

...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Hi, can you please provide some sample data to test with?

Comment: @barrypicker added